# Create a script to run a command line

Tags: scripting

I am using Hotspot Shield VPN, which is now installed on my Linux Mint 19 laptop.
I tried to include an entry in the Startup Application app:

```
hotspotshield connect UK
```

However, it doesn't work. I can only connect manually via the terminal window, which I don't want to do every boot-up.

Q. How can I create a script to include the above command and double-click this from the desktop? And will it work?

Thanks.

Comment: did you try to put this command in file - and add shebang in first line `#!/bin/bash` - and set it executable `xmod +x your_script` ?

Comment: Thanks for your comments.
I have now managed to place the command as an entry in my .Profile file, and that seems to automatically run at startup.

Comment: if my answer (below) helped you then you can mark my answer as accepted. And after few minutes you can also upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you can put code in file (ie. `my_script`) with shebang `#!/bin/bash` in first line

```
#!/bin/bash

hotspotshield connect UK
```

and you can set it executable using `chmod`(change mode) - ie.

```
chmod +x my_script
```

and then you can run it by double click or in command line - and it will use `/bin/bash` to run code in this file.